# onfocus onblur issue javascript multiple instace of same field

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type="text" rel="Credit card number" class="defaultColor" name="cc_num" id="txtCardNumber" runat="server" maxlength="20" onblur="cc_number_saved = this.value; this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');" onfocus="if(this.value != cc_number_saved) this.value = cc_number_saved;"/>
```

I am saving the value of credit card and replacing the non numeric characters onblur and placing them again onfocus (basically space and dashes). This field will get created multiple time if there are more rooms(I mean if user select more than one room, we are populating credit card field for each room in different container.

Curently if i type different credit card information in other room it is replacing the value with the first room, how do I create a different instance for each room for this credit card field.
I have declare the variable in gloabal scope so it is causing issue I beilive. but not sure how do I make it private for each generated input credit card field with current approch.

```
var cc_number_saved = "";
```

Please let me know if it is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery to attach values to the DOM element representing the relevant input.

With an id on the input:

```
<input id = 'input1' >
```

Then you can assign a value to a data-field attached to the input like this:

```
$('#input1').on('blur', function(){
    $(this).data('temp', $(this).val();
}
```

...retaining that value regardless of what you do with the input's value.

And later retrieve it again like this:

```
var originalVal = $('#input1').data('temp');
```

Then apply manipulated value back into the input like this:

```
var newVal = someFunction(originalVal);
$('#input1').val(newVal);
```

...or whatever.

Comment: thanks! input is created dymnamically so ID's are different, I have implemented your idea for all the fields and it works fine!  thanks!